# Can anyone tell my why my gif/Label wont show

Tags: user-interface, jframe, gif

I've inserted the code below. My Jframes pop up, and close when they're supposed to, but nothing shows u inside of my JFrame. It should say "sending..." next to a gif of a loading bar. I've tried everything. I freatly appreciate any and all help. Thank You

```
package image_processor;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in ProjectProperties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
/**
*
* @author root
*/
public class SendingGUI {
public void sending() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sending Image(s)");
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Image(s) Sent!");

ImageIcon gifImage = new ImageIcon("/opt/med-seg-netbeans/med-seg   /senderGUI/ajax-loader.gif");

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Sending, please wait... ",gifImage, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Images Sent. Processing...",gifImage,JLabel.CENTER);

    frame.add(label1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    try{
     Thread.sleep(4000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
    }

    frame.setVisible(false);

    frame2.add(label2);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.setSize(350, 150);
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING,frame2));

    try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
    }

    frame2.setVisible(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct.

I suspect your image URL is incorrect, or alternatively, the Label may not support animated.

**Solution:**

Try using a different image. Ideally a non-animated image.

If you're using Windows, place the image in C:\ drive so the code will read:

```
ImageIcon gifImage = new ImageIcon("C:/image.gif");
```